# Bing map SetCenter doesn't work

Tags: openlayers, bing-maps

I am trying to use Bing maps on my HTML page using OpenLayers and geoEXT. 
the problem is when I change the center of the Bing map nothing happens, also when I try to zoom on the map on certain point like this:

```
Bing.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(rec.get('x'),rec.get('y')).transform('EPSG:4326','EPSG:26191'), 9);
```

It doesn't zoom on this point with the x and y, all I get is the zoom with degree 9.

Here's the code:

```
var Bing;
var apiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
 Bing = new OpenLayers.Map("map");          
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
    var road = new OpenLayers.Layer.Bing({
            name: "Road",
            key: apiKey,
            type: "Road"
        });
        var hybrid = new OpenLayers.Layer.Bing({
            name: "Hybrid",
            key: apiKey,
            type: "AerialWithLabels"
        });
        var aerial = new OpenLayers.Layer.Bing({
            name: "Aerial",
            key: apiKey,
            type: "Aerial"
        });
        Bing.addLayers([road, hybrid, aerial]);
        var center = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-93.27, 44.98).transform(
            'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'
        );      
        Bing.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(-110, 45), 3);

 bingpanel =  new GeoExt.MapPanel({
          region:"center",
          height: 400,
          width: 600,
          map: Bing

      });
```

Answer (score 1):

The "center" variable is never used in your example:

```
var center = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-93.27, 44.98).transform(
            'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'
        );
```

Also, Bing maps take position in decimal degrees so try removing the transform from

```
Bing.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(rec.get('x'),rec.get('y')).transform('EPSG:4326','EPSG:26191'), 9);
```

Comment: sorry i copied wrong the code i have center in my code, but still doesn't work , i removed transform

Comment: it seems like bingmap doesn't accept the setCenter ...

Comment: `Bing.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(-110, 45), 3);` does not work, because the coordinates are not transformed to EPSG:3857. Try `Bing.setCenter(center, 3);` because the var center is already transformed.

Answer (score 1):

setCenter doesn't exists in Bing, use setView instead.

You can check methods and events in the microsoft reference webpage for the Map Class here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427609.aspx

You can find properties for ViewOption objects here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427628.aspx

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se - could you provide a reference or a little background? Click 'edit' to add to your answer.

Comment: Done, sorry I couldn't post the third link:
For examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427608.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to test a simple example first, something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>OpenLayers Demo</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #basicMap {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script>
      function init() {
        map = new OpenLayers.Map("basicMap");
        var apiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        var bingRoad = new OpenLayers.Layer.Bing(
          {
            name: "Road",
            key: apiKey,
            type: "Road"
          }
        );
        //var mapnik         = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
        var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");   // Transform from WGS 1984
        var toProjection   = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857"); // to Spherical Mercator Projection
        //var toProjection   = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); // to Spherical Mercator Projection
        var position       = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-93.27,44.98).transform( fromProjection, toProjection);
        var zoom           = 3; 

        map.addLayer(bingRoad);
        map.setCenter(position, zoom );
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="init();">
    <div id="basicMap"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

once that worked, you can adjust that to include GeoExt. If you want to center or zoom into a specific position, you need to do it in the map call (ie., map = new OpenLayers.Map("basicMap");) rather than in the Bing layer. AFAIK that should work in that way.

Hope this helps,

Comment: i try this, but i still have the same problem, i tried to change the longitude and the latitude i get the same view , it seems that bings didn't take changes, do u have any idea about this problem?

Comment: uhmmm no really, and do you get any error messages? have you tried Firebug to see if some errors appear?

Comment: no i don't have any error with chrome console

Comment: i think i know the source of the error is that i have cartesian coordinate that i transform to lon lat, do i have to transform xy to lon/lat and then do the transform????

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean

Comment: when i try with this example :Bing.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(rec.get('x'),rec.get('y')).transform('EPSG:4326','EPSG:26191'), 9)      i have x and y cartesian coordinate not longitude and latitude, does this transform function convert cartesian (meter) to lat/lon (degree) ?

Comment: I think that transforms longitude/latitude (ie, EPSG:4326) to utm values (ie., EPSG:26191). So, you would need: `OpenLayers.LonLat(rec.get('x'),rec.get('y')).transform('EPSG:26191','EPSG:4326')‌​, 9);` to convert from UTM to long/lat, is that what you need?

Comment: yes exactly, i tried to show the x and y after transform, and it works i get long/lat corresponding to trasformation, but the problem is with the bing map layers when i setCenter nothing happens